# DevDemon Forms - On form submit, URL is stripping out the : from the http://

Tags: devdemon, devdemon-forms

Using DevDemon forms. Have used before on other sites. When click submit, its stripping out the : from the http:// on the redirect.
Any ideas where this is stored as it seems to be taking a default value from somewhere. Have tried to override with return="/contact/thanks" but not recognising this.
Thanks in advance.
Steve

Answer (score 1):

Currently forms doesn't support external redirects. You need to redirect to a template and on that template redirect to an external site.

If you are trying to redirect to an internal page and it isn't working you should contact our support as there might be an issue with your htaccess.